# Recursive function that returns highest value from array

Tags: c, recursion

I need to program a recursive function that returns the maximum value from a one-dimensional array filled with integer numbers, the last one of the values being a 0 (zero) which marks the end of the useful values
of the array. It needs to be without static values and the only parameter that the function has is the pointer to the array. The default structure of the function would be something like -
int max(int* arr); -
I tried solving it but the only solution i can come up with is one that involves me needing more than one parameter to get the highes value from it.
I thought of something like comparing one value with the next from the array but i cant think of how to return the highest value, the example is below.

```
int max(int* arr){
if(*(arr)!=0) 
{
    if (*(arr) > *(arr+1)){
        return max(arr+1);
    }else{
        return max(arr);
    }
}
return *(arr);
```

}

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please do not post code as pictures, it makes it hard to work on it. Instead, post it as text. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to use recursion at all?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Comment: This is surely a homework question.  You won't learn anything by asking someone else to solve it for you.  I'll give you a hint.  Work out what the max function will be looking at with each invocation and and how it will compare with what is returned from the recursive inner call to max.  Think about how it will end.

Comment: Ive been trying for hours thanks for the hint. Also i fixed the image issue sorry im new to SO.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the last value to exit the recursion:

```
int max(int *arr)
{
// The next value is the flag, so the maximum when you have only the last element will be itself
   if(arr[1] == 0) 
       return *arr;
   
   //you check the maximum in the recursion
   int temp = max(arr + 1);

   //you compare the result from you recursion with the current element and return it.
   if(temp > *arr)
      return temp;
   else
      return *arr;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need an else there?  you do realise you're doing his homework and he won't learn.

Comment: @hookenz I don't need the else. It just seeemed more didactic. The `learning` part lies on his attitude: will he try to understand the code or simply copy and paste? I can't decide that for him, I'm just offering some help.

Comment: this is an excercise from a book my teacher recommended that i just couldnt figure out for the life of me, i was going to ask my teacher but i just couldnt get this out of my head thats why i posted it. I am currently looking at the code with python tutor and this is a really cool way to compare variables from an array. Thank you!!

Comment: `max()` fails when the array is only `[0]` as current code accesses outside the array.  I think `if(arr[0] == 0)  return *arr;` will solve that.  Hmmm, a bit of trouble then with negative numbers.   Still doable with skipping the compare when `temp == 0`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I noticed that, but since the function should return an integer... what would be the maximum element of an empty list? I assumed the list should have at least one element. I was trying to put that in the answer but there would be too many IF's to take into account and it would get outside the recursion scope.

Comment: @vmp IAC, an interesting problem.  I suspect the final `0` should be considered part of the list (so at least 1 element), thus any list, with/without negative values would have a minimum value of 0.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica If we make a parallel to C-strings, strlen would return 1 for empty strings because we would be counting the terminator character as well... Anyways, I think this part (what to do with empty list) is easier for him to decide what to do.